# How can I use .startswith() in a python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, debugging

```
def sentence_checker(phrase):
    capital = phrase.capitalize()
    question_words = ('How', 'What', 'Why', 'When', 'Who', 'Which', 'Whose', 'Whom')
    if phrase.startswith(question_words):
         return '{}?'.format(capital)
    else:
        return '{}.'.format(capital)

while True:
    sentence = input('Say Something: ')
    sentence = sentence
    if sentence == '\end':
        break
    else:
        listlist.append(sentence_checker(sentence))

print(' '.join(listlist))
```

I am a beginner in python. This code recognises all the words except 'How'. This is the output:

```
Say Something: how
Say Something: \end
How.
```

Comment: `"how"` does not start with `"How"`, or anything else in your tuple.  Perhaps you should be checking `capital` instead of `phrase`.

Comment: change the if to `if capital.startswith(question_words):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the only was problem was indeed (as commented) that you were using `phrase`, rather than `capital`.

Comment: No, no, no... `startswith()` works just fine with a tuple of prefixes, the problem is checking the original uncapitalized string against a tuple of capitalized prefixes.

Comment: @jasonharper oops, you're totally right, I never used it that way - I will edit the "answer".  Thanks